# Maven tests can't resolve autowired spring boot dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, testing

Spring Boot tests, when executed through Intellij are running fine. But when I run tests with Maven, they fail.

I use this Maven test command:

```
mvn test
```

Reasons found in the surefire plugin report:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.miro.project.controllers.ProjectTest
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.839
> s <<< FAILURE! - in com.miro.project.controllers.ProjectTest
> signupSuccess  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'acmeApplication': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

And in terminal (after tests are executed):

> IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext

In my tests, all dependencies are loaded with *@Autowired* annotation. I am using Java8, Maven 3.6.3 and Spring Boot 2.3.0

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Check if you provide some environment variables when you run your tests in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your classes are visible to Spring. Try checking if every class has the proper annotation (@Component, @Service, @Repository, etc) on them. If acmeApplication.java has your main method, make sure it contains the @EnableAutoConfiguration and @SpringBootApplication annotations in it.

Comment: This is a valid answer, and in some cases, it can help. But in my case, problem was somewhere else. See my answer. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. when Maven is running multiple tests (with **mvn test** command) it
   somehow messes with ports - since every one of these classes is
   using

   TestRestTemplate

So the solution was to call each of these test classes separately. I created a dedicated script and call them one by one:

#! /usr/bin/zsh

```
cd /home/miro/IdeaProjects/acme-project/acme-backend

mvn -Dtest="AcmeControllerTest" test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
mvn -Dtest="AcmeProfileControllerTest" test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
mvn -Dtest="RandomControllerTest" test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

2. I had to explicitly define the environment when running Maven with:

   -Dspring.profiles.active=dev